# Unable to move tmp file to correct folder using [function.move-uploaded-file] CAKEPHP

Tags: php, cakephp, file-upload, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to get files to upload using cakephp

I am currently using a [tutorial](http://www.tuxradar.com/content/cakephp-tutorial-build-file-sharing-application) but have come across some errors, especially with the move-uplaoded-file.

Error : `Indirect modification of overloaded property UploadsController::$data has no effect`

I see that my upload does actually create an array with details of the information in it, it just doesn't pass it to the database or move the tmp file.

Here is my uploading function:

```
function uploadFile() {
    $file = $this->data['Upload']['file'];
    if ($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $id = String::uuid();
        if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'] , APP . 'uploads'.DS.$id)) {
            $this->data['Upload']['uploadID'] = $id;
            $this->data['Upload']['fileName'] = $file['name'];
            $this->data['Upload']['fileSize'] = $file['size'];
            $this->data['Upload']['fileType'] = $file['type'];
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Check permissions on folder..

Comment: had folder in the incorrect directory, but now receiving a different error now `Indirect modification of overloaded property UploadsController::$data has no effect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the data sent by the form (in your case the file itself) you must use 
`$this->request->data` instead of `$this->data`.

I hope this helps.